# Error: Unable to Verify Contract source code

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am a newbie in Solidity and Ethereum smart contract deployment. I have been trying to deploy some contract on Ethereum Testnet - **Ropsten**. I have successfully deployed and published

But, I received the error "**Unable to Verify Contract source code.**" when trying to publish the following source code for this contract: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x811f7cf0f9534f54c4a56c383bbaed73dc88f609#code

I didn't know where did I do wrong.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Test3 {
    uint storageData;
    function set(uint x) public {
        storageData = x;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I don't have enough reputation to comment otherwise I would have but there are very few things that could go wrong here so Ill just go over what you need to do. And you can chat with me on discord or something if you have any other questions. First I assumed you deployed with remix. So go to the settings tab and make sure that on etherscan you selected the same version that is displayed there, otherwise it will not work and then if the optimization box is not checked which is the third checkbox down then select no on etherscan otherwise again it wont work. then you just copy the exact source code into the box and type in the name of the contract and that is it.

Comment: You are right! The problem is the compiler version. I shouldn't use pre-release compiler. Thanks!